# Would a electromagnet be used to detect the presence of a permanent magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, magnetic-flux, magnet

I was wondering if there is any way I could use an electromagnet to detect the presence of a permanent magnet.
I am specifically thinking of using a planar type small coil. Maybe use a core or something that can get saturated by the permanent magnet field.
Do let me know if someone has experience doing something similar. Thank you.

Comment: You are kind of describing the operation of a fluxgate magnetometer.

Comment: Simple LC oscillator can be stopped if a perm. magnet is placed near its coil. The key is to drive LC with very low currents, otherwise PM does not affect the oscillations.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I've never heard of that. Do you have a link?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I have any, but I did it physically many times. Theres even possible to detect magnetic field of Earth. Best is to use oscillator with parallel LC tank with high L and small C (relatively).

Answer (score 2):

The permanent magnet only has a measurable effect when the magnetic field changes, i.e., when you move the magnet relative to the windings (where you basically build a generator), or as you propose, when you feed the electromagnet with a changing current and the materials are driven into nonlinear regions. But that would mean you need to waste a lot of power, and would still need pretty sensitive and complicated control and readout electronics.

This is a classical use case for a Hall effect sensor. That simply measures the Lorentz force on charge carriers traveling through a semiconductor disk.